# Alternatives to Aptana and jQueryWTP for jQuery Eclipse integration

Tags: jquery, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

jQueryWTP is very out of date (jQuery 1.2.6 and Eclipse 3.3), and I don't want to use Aptana just to get code completion (I'm very happy with PDT otherwise). Is there any current solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not to my knowledge.
According to [JQueryBuzz](http://www.jquerybuzz.com/tag/eclipse/), JQueryWTP is the only one based on WTP right now.